# is there a way to change the date format in django/html?

Tags: html, django

i am still new to django and i am following a tutorial but when the guy i had the error the method he used didnt work for me - i am get this error althogh the default format for date is yyyy- mm-dd - any help will be appreciated

> ['“” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD
> format.']

this is my save function that inputs the data into the database

```
def add_seniorEmployee_save(request):
    if request.method!="POST":
        return HttpResponse("Method Not Allowed")
    else:
        first_name=request.POST.get("first_name")
        last_name=request.POST.get("last_name")
        username=request.POST.get("username")
        email=request.POST.get("email")
        password=request.POST.get("password")
        Dob=request.POST.get("Dob")
        Nationality=request.POST.get("Nationality")
        Address=request.POST.get("Address")
        Postcode=request.POST.get("Postcode")
        Telephone=request.POST.get("Telephone")
        Wage=request.POST.get("Wage")
        Passportnumber=request.POST.get("Passportnumber")
        passportexpirydate=request.POST.get("passportexpirydate")
        gender=request.POST.get("gender")
        kinname=request.POST.get("kinname")
        kinrelation=request.POST.get("kinrelation")
        kinaddress=request.POST.get("kinaddress")
        kinphonenumber=request.POST.get("kinphonenumber")
        kinemail=request.POST.get("kinemail")
        #try:
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password,email=email,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,user_type=2)

        user.senioremployee.Dob = Dob
        user.senioremployee.Nationality = Nationality
        user.senioremployee.Address = Address
        user.senioremployee.Postcode = Postcode
        user.senioremployee.Telephone = Telephone
        user.senioremployee.Wage = Wage
        user.senioremployee.Passportnumber = Passportnumber
        user.senioremployee.passportexpirydate = passportexpirydate
        user.senioremployee.gender = gender
        user.senioremployee.profile_pic=""
        user.senioremployee.kinname = kinname
        user.senioremployee.kinrelation = kinrelation
        user.senioremployee.kinaddress = kinaddress
        user.senioremployee.kinphonenumber = kinphonenumber
        user.senioremployee.kinemail = kinemail
        user.save()
```

this is the model for my senior employee who i am adding to the database

this is the model to create the customer user

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data=((1,"Admin"),(2,"senioremployee"),(3,"employee"))
    user_type=models.CharField(default=1,choices=user_type_data,max_length=20)




class senioremployee(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Dob = models.DateField()
    Nationality = models.TextField()
    Address = models.TextField()
    Postcode = models.TextField()
    Telephone = models.TextField()
    Wage = models.TextField()
    Passportnumber = models.TextField()
    passportexpirydate = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_pic = models.FileField()
    kinname = models.TextField()
    kinrelation = models.TextField()
    kinaddress = models.TextField()
    kinphonenumber = models.TextField()
    kinemail = models.TextField()
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Comment: Use a *form*. You should validate, clean and process user input through froms.

Answer (score 0):

problem is with this line `Dob=request.POST.get("Dob")` you are saving a string in Dob , you need to convert it to date format. use strptime() from datetime module for conversion to date object and then save to the database.

Comment: how can i use it

Comment: assuming Dob = '2020Dec30', then Dob=datetime.strptime(Dob,"%Y%b%d")

Comment: Dob_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(Dob,"%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        user.senioremployee.Dob = Dob_date - it didnt work its still same error

Comment: try, user.senioremployee.Dob = Dob_date.date()

Comment: thanks for your help it still not working is there another way i can do it